# How to change the name of the downloaded file when editing in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, image

```
if (isset($article) && isset($article->id))


    <option value="0" {{ ($article->published == 0) ? 'selected' : '' }}>Publish</option>
    <option value="1" {{ ($article->published == 1) ? 'selected' : '' }}>No publish</option>
@else
    <option value="0" selected disabled>No publish</option>
    <option value="1" disabled>Publish</option>
@endif
<img src="{{URL::to('/images').'/'.$article->image_path}}" alt="">
<input type="file" name="image_path" />


function upload(Request $request){

  $image = $request->file('image_path');

  $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

  $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);
  return $new_name; 
}


   public function update(Request $request, Article $article)
{
    $article->update($request->except('slug'));


    $article->categories()->detach();

    if($request->input('categories'))  :
        $article->categories()->attach($request->input('categories'));
    endif;
    return redirect()->route('admin.article.index');    
}
```

I need when I go to the editing page, and there is a picture, to be remembered otherwise when entering, even if it is there and I don not edit anything, then the database remains empty.

When I create a new post and save a new picture everything is fine, but when I edit, I need to remember what is already there, and if I do not change,  then save the same to the database unless I upload another.

Comment: So update the file name only if a file was uploaded.

Comment: How to store file in database? Like only name or full path?? If you stored name of the file in database then you need to check or match that file exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function update(Request $request, Article $article)
{
    $article->update($request->except('slug', 'image_path'));

    if ($request->hasFile('image_path')) {

        // Add your file upload logic here
        $image = $request->file('image_path');
        $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);

        $article->image_path = $new_name;
        $article->save();
    }

    $article->categories()->detach();

    if ($request->has('categories')) {
        $article->categories()->attach($request->input('categories'));
    }

    return redirect()->route('admin.article.index');
}
```

Source [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files)

You can also read more about file uploads to enhance your code: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#files

Comment: I have updated the answer, try using `hasFile` instead of `has`. Also, you need to add your file upload logic in that update method.

Comment: I don’t understand how to insert my upload

Comment: That is the upload function you added in your question: `function upload(Request $request)`

Comment: Yes, she, but I don’t understand how to insert it into update

Comment: I have updated my answer with the upload method. It should be working now.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check or match in the database that file exists or not like:

I assume you have update perticular record. Means single record. And 'image_path' means name of the image right?

```
  If( $article->image_field_name == $request->input('image_path'){
          //Your update logic here.

  }
```